# How to prevent test conflicts when automating testing?

Tags: automated-testing

What is some advice in organizing automated testing so that they do not interfere with each other? For example eventually automated tests can get out of control if it is run on the same data. Obviously a new instance is required but does your automated test have an additional testing suite to set up preliminary data and then clean the instance after each test or set of tests?

Comment: Can you please give some real world example so can help you once understood your question..

Comment: Real world example. Lets say i have a calender app  where i post daily tasks. Lets say i can only post 2 tasks per day. We could write the automated test cases to delete the task after posting so no need to reset the database each time we run our regression suite. Or we could reset the testing suite each time.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the replies on [the question asked here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/controlling-database-state-in-selenium-ui-testing/12223#12223).

The easiest way is to create database scripts which clean up and reset data whenever you're running a test suite. That way, you'll have the same starting point every time - so that excludes unexpected data as a reason your tests fail.