# What do I need to do if dropdown takes more time to populate 1st element from dropdown list?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

What do I need to do if drop down take time to populate 1st element from drop down list?

[image]

```
Select Cdropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ClientId']")));
        Cdropdown.selectByVisibleText("centralpen-ak-01");

Thread.sleep(3000);

Select Edropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='EnvironmentId']")));
            Edropdown.selectByValue("1121");
```

For loading the drop down it should take the time I have used-
`Thread.sleep(3000);` but still the element is not found. What should I do in such a case?

Comment: Is it works for first dropdown? or getting issue with both?

Comment: Its work for first dropdown for second its fail

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error which got after ran the code:   Cannot locate element with text: centralpen-prod-m-01
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 11):

Do you think that time is the problem here?

If so try to increase the time you are providing in Thread.sleep(); and see it that works out for you.

If its not the time, then did you try to find out what the problem is? Are you getting any error?

Comment: While that's one thing to consider trying, we may want to ask ourselves if Thread.sleep() is what we want at all - do we want to rely on a certain amount of time if time itself isn't a requirement?

Comment: Increase sleep time? And this is most upvoted answer? Will **THIS** be representative of the future quality of the answers here? Sad day...

Answer (score 3):

adding `Thread.sleep(3000)` is not a good way to handle synchronization, rather use implicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Implicit wait allows your browser to wait until element is visible or until time set by you, whichever is earlier.

Comment: Definitely agree. I wrote a post a while back about the [dangers of using sleep](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/3765/65).

Answer (score 3):

**1:**

```
Select Cdropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ClientId']")));
Cdropdown.selectByVisibleText("centralpen-ak-01");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Select Edropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='EnvironmentId']")));
                    Edropdown.selectByIndex(0);
//check your index, starting from 0 which item you have to select & add corresponding index of that.
```

OR
**2:**
You may try with same method-`selectByVisibleText` as like 1st dropdown

**3:** 
Otherwise You may try with **explicitly wait-**

```
 //Selecting value from 2nd drop down using visible text

    Select mydrpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("EnvironmentId")));
    mydrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("add element in dropdown");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("EnvironmentId")));
```

Comment: I try both way but still the script is not work. I think its application issue for populating the drop down

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
WebDriverWait wait;
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement));
```